# pylab.plot exists but can't be imported?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

EDIT: This example comes directly from the "ein" documentation for ipython notebooks in emacs: https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook

With fresh installation of ipython on Mac OS Yosemite:

```
ipython
```

> ```
> Python 2.7.9 (default, Feb 12 2015, 17:01:13)
> Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> IPython 3.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
> ?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
> %quickref -> Quick reference.
> help      -> Python's own help system.
> object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
> ```

```
In [1]: %pylab
```

> ```
> Using matplotlib backend: MacOSX
> Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib
> ```

```
In [2]: dir(pylab)
```

long spew, but I verified that `'plot'` is in the list

```
In [3]: from pylab import plot
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-3-8618f02f2b7e> in <module>()
> ----> 1 from pylab import plot
>
> ImportError: cannot import name plot
> ```

No idea what's wrong.  Googled the exact error message and didn't see anything helpful.

Comment: Have you tried `from matplotlib.pylab import plot` ?

Comment: @BassemDy that did it ... I wonder why others reported the former `from pylab import plot` as working?  The example I cited comes directly from this site: https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook

Comment: @Reb.Cabin `import matplotlib`  in default python console and then `print matplotlib.__version__`. What does it output?

Comment: @Reb.Cabin also `print matplotlib.__file__` in default Python console. Then repeat it in ipython

Comment: @Reb.Cabin I think a problem has occurred during the installation of the packages, @Alik is spot on requesting version number and file locations. While what I suggested is a workaround, `from pylab import plot` should work.

Comment: Why are you running both `%pylab` and `from pylab import plot`? After `%pylab` you can `pylab.plot`

Comment: i got this working on a different machine.  Something is indeed wrong with the python installation on the other machine, but I can't investigate it now.  I will continue the investigation when I can get back to the other machine.  In the meantime, I have been reading all the comments and voting up the helpful ones.